# How to match phonemic transcriptions with a single vowel except if a condition applies

Tags: r, regex

I have phonemic transcriptions of English words such as these:

```
test <- c("ˈsɜːtnli", "ˈtwɛnti", "ˈfɒksi", "kɑːnt", "ʧeɪnʤd", "vɪkˈtɔːrɪə", "wɒznt", "ðeər", "dɪdnt",
          "ˈdɪzni", "ˈəʊnli", "ˈfæbrɪks", "sɪˈkjʊərɪti", "ˈnjuːzˌpeɪpər", "ɑhɑː")
```

I'd like to match mono-syllabic words, i.e., words that contain a single vowel. My set of phonemic vowels is this:

```
vowel <- "iː|aɪ|ɔː|ɔɪ|əʊ|ɛə|eɪ|aʊ|eə|uː|ɑː|ɪə|ɜː|ʊə|ə|ɪ|ɒ|ʊ|ʌ|æ|e|ɑ|ɛ|i"
```

Using `str_count` and the vector `vowel` as pattern, I'm able to match a fairly good set of words:

```
library(stringr) 
test[str_count(test, vowel) == 1]
[1] "kɑːnt"  "ʧeɪnʤd" "wɒznt"  "ðeər"   "dɪdnt"
```

However, `wɒznt` and `dɪdnt`can be seen as bi-syllabic (as the `n`sound can replace a vowel so that `nt` counts as a second vowel). So the question is, how can I match mono-syllabic words except those that end in `nt`?

What I've tried so far is this set operation, which works well but looks clumsy:

```
setdiff(test[str_count(test, vowel) == 1], test[str_count(test, paste0("[^", vowel, "]nt$")) == 1])
[1] "kɑːnt"  "ʧeɪnʤd" "ðeər"
```

I'd much rather have a single more concise regex. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just add `nt` to your list of vowels?

Comment: For `nt` to count as a syllable, it must not be preceded by a `vowel` and must occur at string end.

Comment: Doesn't `kant` end with `nt`? I understand you want `"ʧeɪnʤd" "ðeər"` as output. Or do you mean if the vowel is long, the `nt` rule does not apply?

Comment: Try  https://ideone.com/L7rLsR

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/drs7Vw/1

Comment: So, is https://ideone.com/E8nYhp what you need? Or https://ideone.com/tfiQOH?

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions do provide the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```r
test <- c("ˈsɜːtnli", "ˈtwɛnti", "ˈfɒksi", "kɑːnt", "ʧeɪnʤd", "vɪkˈtɔːrɪə", "wɒznt", "ðeər", "dɪdnt",
          "ˈdɪzni", "ˈəʊnli", "ˈfæbrɪks", "sɪˈkjʊərɪti", "ˈnjuːzˌpeɪpər", "ɑhɑː")
vowel <- "iː|aɪ|ɔː|ɔɪ|əʊ|ɛə|eɪ|aʊ|eə|uː|ɑː|ɪə|ɜː|ʊə|ə|ɪ|ɒ|ʊ|ʌ|æ|e|ɑ|ɛ|i"
library(stringr) 
p <- paste0("^(?!.*(?<!",vowel,")nt$)(?:(?!",vowel,").)*(?:",vowel,")(?:(?!",vowel,").)*$")
test[str_detect(test, p)]
## => [1] "kɑːnt"  "ʧeɪnʤd" "ðeər"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/tfiQOH). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a3f7l2/1/). The pattern means

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?<!",vowel,")nt$)` - immediately to the right, there must not be any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with `nt` (not preceded with any of the specified `vowel` sound sequences) and end of string
- `(?:(?!",vowel,").)*`  - any char but a line break char, zero or more times as many as possible, that does not start a `vowel` char sequence
- `(?:",vowel,")` - any of the specified `vowel` sound sequences
- `(?:(?!",vowel,").)*`  - any char but a line break char, zero or more times as many as possible, that does not start a `vowel` char sequence
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat concise solution (thanks to @G5W for the decisive hint):

```
vowel_cc <- paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\|", "", vowel), ""))), collapse = "")
vowel_cc
[1] "iːaɪɔəʊɛeuɑɜɒʌæ"

test[str_count(test, paste0(vowel, "|[^", vowel_cc, "]+nt$")) == 1]
[1] "kɑːnt"  "ʧeɪnʤd" "ðeər"
```

This solution uses a vector `vowel_cc` consisting of all *unique* characters in `vowels`. These serve as input for a negated character class. The pattern specifies `nt` as one of the `vowel` alternatives on the condition that it be preceded by one or more non-`vowel_cc`s and occur at string end.

Comment: This is a wrong pattern because `[^...]` is a *negated character class* that matches a single char other than the one defined in the class, and thus `nt` inside it is not matched as a sequence, but as separate `n` and `t` chars, so it will not match neither `n`, nor `t` separately. Your "vowels" are *multicharacter* substrings, so you have to use a tempered greedy token here.

Comment: `nt` is not inside the negated character class, it is outside it. All that is negated are the vowels.

Comment: Yes, and `vowels` contain multicharacter entries, see `iː|aɪ|ɔː|ɔɪ|əʊ|ɛə|eɪ|aʊ|eə|uː|ɑː|ɪə|ɜː|ʊə`. Actually, `|` inside a character class is also a pipe char, not an alternation operator.

Comment: Thanks for this observation. I've updated the solution accordingly.